# Getting a timeout error on a newly created Apache2 web server

Tags: debian, web-server, apache2

I created a new Debian 12 web server through Vultr. I have uploaded my simple little website up to the `/var/www/html` directory and when I try to navigate to the ip address, I get a `The connection has timed out` error. I'm fairly new to setting up a website on a basic Apache2 server, so I don't really know where to start debugging this.

What would the first few steps to debug this? Thanks.

Comment: Start by researching how Apache is configured. Determine the Apache version, Apache Root directory, Virtual Hosts, firewall, and firewall rules. Then update your question with relevant details. Hint: `Timed out` usually means a firewall blocking the port or Apache is not configured to listen on that port. Your post does not show how you are accessing your server. Use the CLI `curl` to do testing. Use a browser to verify how your site appears once you have the fundamentals configured.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the issue was that I didn't have port 80 open. I ran `ufw allow 80` and my site was instantly accessible from the IP address.